# Latex not rendering with canvaskit flutter

Tags: flutter, latex, flutter-dependencies, flutter-web, canvaskit

I'm using flutter wub with flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true
I need canvaskit for my richtext editor, there are some know issues if you don't use it : https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/49860
if you test this example app on flutter web with

```
flutter run -d chrome --dart-define=FLUTTER_WEB_USE_SKIA=true 

import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:catex/catex.dart';

class CatexExample extends StatelessWidget {


@override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      body: Center(
        child: CaTeX(r'\sum'),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

you need :

```
catex: ^0.0.1+7
```

if anyone has a solution to display latex with canvaskit enabled..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay if anyone has the same problem, i switched to `flutter_math` and it works!